# Azure Funtion: Powershell command New-AzureRmVM never returns

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I've got a powershell script that I use to build a VM.

```
# Variables for common values
$resourceGroup = "AAA-Production3"
$location = "West US 2"
$vmName = "AAA-Prod-SVR1"
$SubnetName = "AAA-PROD-SUBNET01"
$NamevNET = "AAA-PROD-VNET"
$Namepublicdns = "AAA-PROD-ADF01-IP01"
$NameNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP = 'Default-allow-rdp'
$NameNetworkSecurityGroup = 'AAA-SVR1-NSG'
$NameVNic = "AAA-PROD-VNIC01"
$VMSize = 'Standard_D1_v2'

# Create user object 
$cred = Get-Credential -Message "Enter a username and password for the virtual machine."
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroup -Location $location
$subnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $SubnetName -AddressPrefix 10.50.1.0/24
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name $NamevNET -AddressPrefix 10.50.1.0/24 -Subnet $subnetConfig

# Create a public IP address and specify a DNS name 
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name "$Namepublicdns$(Get-Random)" -AllocationMethod Static -IdleTimeoutInMinutes 4

# Create an inbound network security group rule for port 3389 
$nsgRuleRDP = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $NameNetworkSecurityGroupRuleRDP  -Protocol Tcp `
  -Direction Inbound -Priority 1000 -SourceAddressPrefix * -SourcePortRange * -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
  -DestinationPortRange 3389 -Access Allow

# Create a network security group 
$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -Name $NameNetworkSecurityGroup -SecurityRules $nsgRuleRDP

# Create a virtual network card and associate with public IP address and NSG
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $NameVNic -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location `
  -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id -NetworkSecurityGroupId $nsg.Id

# Create a virtual machine configuration
$vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $VMSize | `
Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -Windows -ComputerName $vmName -Credential $cred | `
Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer -Skus 2016-Datacenter -Version latest | `
Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -Id $nic.Id

# Create a virtual machine
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Location $location -VM $vmConfig
```

Everything runs fine, but when it gets to the end, the New-AzureRmVM script never returns or exits.  If I disconnect my machine from the net, I'll get a message about a long running process, but other than that, the shell appears to be locked up.

Any ideas how to get the command to exit so I can reuse the shell?

Comment: Azure function has a default timeout and creating a VM can take a while.

Comment: I've been using the VM for an hour now.  Everything deployed as expected.  The command line still hasn't returned and the shell is frozen.  Won't respond to Ctrl-C or any other keyboard command.  Tried this with several variations of the 'build a VM script' and the result is the same each time - a frozen shell.

Comment: @DonaldAirey I think you cannot finish the script in Azure Function. Because when you run the command  ```Get-Credential```, it needs you to enter username and password with a window. But Azure Function does not support user interaction.